# failed to open stream, permission denied even tho permissions are set

Tags: php, windows, xampp, file-permissions, bing-api

I'm working with the bing-ads api and try to download a report to a local folder.

I already found out the user that is executing php using

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

which resulted in "dl-dominikl-pc\dolo"

I gave that user full control of the "reports" folder.

The code-part that is failing is:

```
fopen($downloadPath, 'wb');
```

with `$downloadPath` being `"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm\\bingAds\\examples\\reports"`

Comment: Are you sure `C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\bingAds\examples\reports` is a file, not a directory?

Comment: Turns out I actually managed to read over that 100 times and it was the wrong path. Really werid that it showed this error tho. Thanks a lot @Saitama !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Saitama for reminiding me to check my path which didn't point to a file!